# How to use custom filter in Minimal Api .net 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, minimal-apis

After decoding the token generated in another application, I need to check for an expire. I used OnActionExecuting in web app but not working this method in minimal api.

Now I'm catching it by checking the response, but I need a better solution than this.

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(autoMapper);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("BearerAuthentication").AddScheme<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BearerAuthendicationHandler>("BearerAuthentication", null);
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapGet("/countries", async (HttpContext http, CountryService service) =>
 {
     if (http.Response.StatusCode == 401) return Results.Unauthorized();    
      var result = service.GetAll(http.Request.Headers["lang"]);
     return Results.Ok(result);
 });
```

BearerAuthendicationHandler.cs

```
public class BearerAuthendicationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public BearerAuthendicationHandler(
        Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock
        ) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        try
        {
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var token = authHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                string secret = "secret_key";
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
                var claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validations, out var tokenSecure);
                var exp = claims.Claims.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "exp").Value;
                var timeStamp = long.Parse(exp);
                var timeStampNow = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
                if (timeStamp < timeStampNow)
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header"));
                }

                Response.StatusCode = 200;
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), null, "")));
            }
            else
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header"));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could try to create a custom middleware to validate the token. In custom middleware, it checks every request, if the token of this request handler is expired, it doesn't care where this token is generated from. You could refer to this [helpful article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/19/net-6-create-and-validate-jwt-tokens-use-custom-jwt-middleware) for code example.